# Load the main js-files while user login and we dont need them right now?

Tags: javascript

I have a web application with a lot of graphic interfaces (charts, grids etc.). For that we have different solutions (Telerik, Syncfusiuon etc.) and got the best of every group of frameworks.

In total we have Javascript files of around 4 to 5MB and we can't reduce their size at the moment.

I have a login page in which we don't need any of the frameworks.
Is it possible to use the time while the user logs himself in and download the Javascript files into the browser cache using an async methodology in the background?

Comment: if you use `async` or load the files last (bottom of the page), doesn't that make it a bit faster?

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the javascripts.  This way you can put them in pages where you're going to use it.